# Align multiple piece of SVG to create extendable container

Tags: html, css, svg, alignment

I'm trying to create a box which will contain content that will expand depending on it's size. The box is made of 3 SVG (Top, Center which repeats-y, Bottom). But I can't manage to align them properly. I have checked dozen of times in Illustrator these have the same size and distance between lines. It should keep the ratio and align easily.

I have created a test case  which I can't manage to fix :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 400px;
}
img {
  display: block;
}
.top,
.bottom {
  width: 100%;
}
.corpus {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: url('http://f.cl.ly/items/1G3o0j0e1S32301k3y18/corpus.svg');
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/3m3u3D2p1o0W2e2n1T1B/top.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="corpus"></div>
  <div class="bot">
    <img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/0z0M3u3h1f401u1T351d/bot.svg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't aware. Here we go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVG files have viewBox attributes but do not have preserveAspectRatio set. If omitted preserveAspectRatio defaults to xMidYMid. You're expecting the shapes to deform to fit the spaces you've allocated to them but they won't do that.

Add preserveAspectRatio="none" to the SVG files (at least the bottom one anyway) to fix this.